# Is there an easy way to convert Excel files to SAS format using SASonDemand on a Macbook?

Tags: excel, sas, sas-studio

I have several data sets on exel. I am a Macbook user and I use SASonDemand (the online version). How can I convert the excel files to SAS format? I need the files for further analysis on SAS.

I tried to watch YouTube videos but I am too new to understand.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Ask-the-Expert/How-Do-I-Read-and-Write-Excel-Files-Using-SAS-Q-amp-A-Slides-and/ta-p/791230

Answer (score 0):

you can use libname statement, one of the easy way to do. So if your excel file is in a particular location. All you need to do is

```
libname mylib XLSX "/home/user/yourexcelfile.XLSX";
```

Once you do this you can access excel file as SAS dataset

Comment: Can you tell me in detail how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer (Mac/Windows) doesn't matter for the cloud application.

1. upload your file to the cloud server
   Go to the Server Files and Folders Pane
   Click on the up arrow icon
   Follow GUI to upload files
2. Use an import procedure/task to import the data
   Find the file path of your file. Right click it in Servers Files Folders and select properties. Copy the path.
   Use this path in Proc Import or the Import Task. Note what data name you save the file to for the next step.
3. Verify the imported data set is correct
   Open the file by navigating to the work library and opening the file. Ensure fields were imported as expected.
4. Proceed with desired next steps.

Here's a webinar that outlines this process.
https://communities.sas.com/t5/Ask-the-Expert/How-Do-I-Read-and-Write-Excel-Files-Using-SAS-Q-amp-A-Slides-and/ta-p/791230